# model theory of non-reduced schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory

In model theory one studies Boolean algebras of definable sets of complete theories. For many theories definable sets are in direct correspondence with geometric objects, for example, definable sets of an algebraically closed field $k$ are, by quantifier elimination (or Chevalley's theorem), contstructible subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

**Q1**: is there a model-theoretic context, known or conjectural, where (certain) definable sets would correspond to non-reduced schemes?

The Boolean algebra of definable sets of a model can be defined as the collection of definable subsets of Cartesian powers of the universum of the model containing some basic definable sets and closed under various natural operations: Boolean operations, Cartesian products, projections, taking a fibre (if you are willing to allow parameters). It seems to me that nothing prevents one from taking an algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field as a universum, taking some collection of non-reduced basic subvarieties of its Cartesian powers, and closing it under finite unions, scheme-theoretic intersections, scheme-theoretic images under projections, fibre products over the base field. This will generate a certain Boolean algebra.

Of course, in order to realize this Boolean algebra as a Boolean algebra of subsets of a set, as the formalism of model theory forces us to do, one would have to take a Stone dual, which is going to be very big, it seems.

**Q2**: Did this idea ever appear in literature?